Connection attempt failed to PostgreSQL Docker Container and running Spring Boot on local computer not as a container
So I am trying to develop a simple application in Java Maven (Spring-Boot) with some endpoints. I have a docker-compose file, as for now I am trying just to run the postgres on it without the app.

After running in the terminal docker compose build, docker compose up, the postgres is starting, i can even access it with docker exec -it doc-pgsql-container /bash/bin so it is working.
Now, this is my application.properties:

After running in the terminal mvn spring-boot:run, I get this error, does anybody know how to solve it?
Error
I tried even changing the names of the services in the docker-compose.yaml. On localhost it is working, but I want it to try with postgres on a docker container.

Don't post pictures of code and use MarkDown

If your application is running on the host system, the database is in a container, and the database container has published ports:, then (using Docker Desktop or native Docker on Linux) the application should be able to see the database on localhost and the first ports: number.

Are you able to access that db using pg admin? If you are able to access there it should work since you are doing port mapping

Yes, I can acces db using terminal
